# Returning a Reference to Me

Tags: language-agnostic

This is such a labor savor, but I am wondering if it's a bad practice?

Suppose I had a String Manipulation class that had various sub that altered the string. Then I changed all those subs to functions that still altered the string but then returned a reference to "Me" so I could chain procedures like this:

```
WriteLine myClass.Change1(someParemeter).Change2(someOtherParameter).Change3().Text
```

The class will do change 1 then return itself so change 2 is performed on the changed value and so.

I really like it because I'm lazy.

I'm suspicious of it because I haven't seen it commonly used and I really like it:)

Comment: People do this ALL the time. Like in every language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually called [Method Chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining).

Answer (score 0):

This is called "method chaining".  There are varying opinions on whether it's a good thing or not.